# How can I dynamically allocate a CFile type of variable? (C++, CFile, new)

Tags: c++, mfc, cfile

```
static TCHAR BASED_CODE szFilter[] = _T("YUV Files|*.yuv|")
CFileDialog fileDlg(TRUE, _T("yuv"), _T("bus.yuv"), OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY, szFilter);
if (fileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    CString pathName = fileDlg.GetPathName();
    CFile* pImgFile = NULL;
    pImgFile = new CFile(pathName, CFile::modeRead || CFile::typeBinary);
}
```

I refer to an example in the following site. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b569d0t4.aspx

```
static TCHAR BASED_CODE szFilter[] = _T("YUV Files|*.yuv|")
CFileDialog fileDlg(TRUE, _T("yuv"), _T("bus.yuv"), OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY, szFilter);
if (fileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    CString pathName = fileDlg.GetPathName();
    CFile imgFile;
    CFileException e;
    if (!imgFile.Open(pathName, CFile::modeRead || CFile::typeBinary, &e))
    {
        TRACE(_T("File could not be opened %d\n"), e.m_cause);
    }
}
```

I refer to the first example in the following site. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwbccf8z.aspx

---

I used the method of CFile, Open, in the second code.

For the upper code, how can I open the file?

When I use dynamic allocation, is it automatically open the file?

```
imgLength = pImgFile->GetLength();
CString str;
str.Format(_T("Your SYSTEM.INI file is %I64u bytes long."), imgLength);
AfxMessageBox(str);
```

I tried to append this code to the first code.

It works without any problems, and I think the variable, pImgFile, points the address of the file well.

Comment: Yes, passing a filename to the constructor opens the file immediately (read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cz0a83sb.aspx)).  Also, the code needs to use `|` instead of `||` to combine bit flags. And do not forget to `delete` the object when you are done using it.

Comment: Thank you. I felt documentation is really important for me to learn MFC. I didn't know it includes the results according to the number of parameter.I saw only parameters and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there is no need to create a `CFile` on the heap.
There are several constructors of `CFile`:

```
CFile( );
CFile(
   CAtlTransactionManager* pTM
);
CFile(
   HANDLE hFile 
);
CFile(
   LPCTSTR lpszFileName,
   UINT nOpenFlags 
);
CFile(
   LPCTSTR lpszFileName,
   UINT nOpenFlags,
   CAtlTransactionManager* pTM
);
```

The fourth and the fifth constructors call `Open` internally. So they do open the file.

The other problem is that you should use `operator |` not `||` to combine open flags.

I'd *suggest using the default CFile constructor* and then call `Open`. Please note that it wont throw an exception in case of error (returns `FALSE` instead) and you wont need to place `try/catch` around it. Optionally you can also pass `CFileException*` to `Open` to get more information if it fails.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Thanks to your easy explanation, I understood. I will change my code to default file constructor.